Quick auto-closing popups when using Nested App Authentication (NAA)
I'm trying to implement Nested App Authentication to transition my outlook add-in away from using legacy exchange tokens. I'm successfully able to get a valid graph API token, but only accompanying some poor user experience caveats when in a browser.
Using Chrome, if a user gets logged out and then logs back in, when they try to use the add-in again, they fail to get the token silently and instead get a quick popup that automatically closes and they get a token. On emails after that, it gets the token silently.
Is this normal behavior? Feels like they should be able to get the token silently in this case since they already consented to the required permissions. (This can also cause them to not be able to get a token at all if the browser blocks that quick popup. This is more of an issue with firefox where for some reason we see 2 popups instead of 1 and sometimes get a popup frozen open and blank, unsure if that's related or not). Considering if we should look to a non-NAA method to avoid these issues.
I don't see this quick popup when using Outlook Desktop for Mac, everything seems to work perfectly there.
The auth relevant parts of my code
export const getMsalConfig = (instance: string): Configuration => {
  let config =  {
    auth: {
      clientId: getClientId(instance),
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
      redirectUri: "https://localhost:3000/auth.html",
      postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://localhost:3000/auth.html",
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: "localStorage",
    },
    system: {},
  };


export default function App({ isOfficeInitialized }: Props) {

  const [msalInstance, setMsalInstance] = React.useState<IPublicClientApplication>();

  useEffect(() => {
    createNestablePublicClientApplication(getMsalConfig(instance))
      .then(res => {
        setMsalInstance(res);
      }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });

  }, [instance])

  return (
    <>
    {msalInstance &&
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
    <AppErrorBoundary>
      <GlobalStyle />
        <Root>
          ... <DoThing>
        </Root>
    </AppErrorBoundary>
    </MsalProvider>
}</>
  );
}


export default function DoThing({}: Props) {

  const accountIdentifiers = {
    username: "foo@example.com" // TODO genericify
  }
  const request = {
    loginHint: "foo@example.com",
    scopes: ["User.Read", "Mail.ReadWrite.Shared"]
  }

  const useMsalResult = useMsal();
  const msalInstance = useMsalResult['instance'];
  // @ts-ignore
  const inProgress = useMsalResult['inProgress'];
  // @ts-ignore
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();

  // @ts-ignore
  const {login, error } = useMsalAuthentication(InteractionType.Silent, request, accountIdentifiers);


  const doAction = async () => {
    // Code here gets an ewsToken that we currently use

    // Try to get a graph API token
    let graphApiToken = null;
    let graphApiError = null;
    try {
      const account = msalInstance.getActiveAccount();
      if (!account) {
        throw Error("No active account found");
      }

      const tokenRequest = {
        scopes: ["User.Read", "Mail.ReadWrite.Shared"],
        account: account
      };
      const tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest);
      graphApiToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
    } catch ($error) {
      graphApiError = error ?? new Error("Failed to obtain a graph API token silently");
      console.error(graphApiError.message);
    }

    // If we didn't silently get a graph api token and we didn't get a ewsToken, we'll try to more noisily
    // acquire a graph api token
    try {
      if (!restToken && !graphApiToken) {
        if (inProgress == InteractionStatus.None) {
          try {
            await login(InteractionType.Popup, request);
          } catch (popupError) {
            if (popupError.errorCode === "popup_window_error") {
              throw new Error("Popup blocked by browser. Please enable popups and try again.");
            }
          }
        } else {
          console.error("interaction already in progress");
        }

        try {
          const account = msalInstance.getActiveAccount();
          if (!account) {
            throw Error("No active account found");
          }

          const tokenRequest = {
            scopes: ["User.Read", "Mail.ReadWrite.Shared"],
            account: account
          };
          const tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest);
          graphApiToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
        } catch ($error) {
          graphApiError = error;
          console.error(graphApiError.message);
          throw graphApiError;
        }
      }

    } catch (error) {
      graphApiError = error ?? new Error("Failed to obtain a graph API token");
    }

    if (!ewsToken && !graphApiToken) {
      onError({
        context: 'Unable to process this message.',
        error:
          ewsError ??
          graphApiError ??
          new Error(
            'There is no API support to obtain a callback token in this environment.'
          ),
      });
      return;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!msalInstance) {
      doAction();
    }
  }, [msalInstance]); 

  return <Root>{// some components here}</Root>;
}

